# vagrant up error when scripting git commit

Tags: shell, scripting, gitlab, vagrant

I'm tasked with making a shell script for part of a project in college, basically, it automates adding MySQL, java, and Gradle and then clones two projects. it then runs a couple of queries in MySQL and sends the output to a text file. I then have to commit it as the txt file gets added but I got an error which isn't clear to me here is the bottom of my vagrant script with the commit that isn't working

chmod 400 mock_key.key

echo "cloning repository..."
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add mock_key.key; git clone git@gitlab.cs.cf.ac.uk:username/mock-repo.git'

cd mock-repo
sudo mysql < tests5.sql > results5.txt

git config --global user.email "email"
git config --global user.name "username"

git add .
git commit -m "added result file"
ssh-agent -c 'ssh-add mock_key.key;
git push'

SHELL
end

the error I get from the command line when I've done vagrant up is

```
default: installing gitlab deployment key...
default: cloning repository...
default: Identity added: gitlab_sakila_keypair.key (gitlab_sakila_keypair.key)
default: Cloning into 'sakila'...
default: Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '131.251.168.40' to the list of known hosts.
default: changing  resource directory
default: ~/sakila ~
default: adding schema...
default: populating db...
default: ~
default: installing gitlab deployment key...
default: cloning repository...
default: Identity added: mock_key.key (vagrant@localhost.localdomain)
default: Cloning into 'mock-repo'...
default: [master 1cba41d] added result file
default:  1 file changed, 26 insertions(+)
default:  create mode 100644 results5.txt
default: usage: ssh-agent [-c | -s] [-Dd] [-a bind_address] [-E fingerprint_hash]
default:                  [-P pkcs11_whitelist] [-t life] [command [arg ...]]
default:        ssh-agent [-c | -s] -k
```

The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.

Comment: I cant find any error here. Or is it just the non-zero error code from SSH ?

Comment: im not to sure thats all it displays for me

Comment: vagrant up --debug &> vagrant.log.  - Try this to see more info

Comment: ok so after a lot of trial and error I figured out and changed the last part of the commit just before the push to ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add ~/mock_key.key; git push' @rootkonda thanks for the vagrant up --debug > vagrant.log that actually showed me something new and something that could help me in the future